# Custom access denied message OpenSSH server

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I just wonder if there is anyway to set a custom access denied message instead of: Permission denied (publickey).

Or, anyway to display any kind of message to the user trying to login.

I'm after to tell anybody that tries to login to get a f**k off message..

Comment: The message you get is from your client. If you want a different message, recompile your ssh client with the message you want. The server doesn't send any message. Specifically the server sends the a packet type 51 (ie SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE). https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252#section-5.1

Comment: Don't bother. They're all bots anyway.

Comment: Then it was as I expected, but now I know..